# Reference for Green functions of Elliptic Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I have known that there exists Green function for harmonic function. But when I read some article, I also came across Green functions for general elliptic operators like these class：
$$Lu=u_{xx}+u_{yy}+1/yu_y$$
in a ball belongs to $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Just under classical sense, not weak sense)

I do wonder that which book or article can I result.

Thanks in advance!